# Show name of theorem in thref

Tags: cross-referencing, ntheorem

Is there a (more or less automatic) way to reference theorems by their name rather than by their numbering? Let be explain:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thref]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[stupid theorem]
\label{thm:stupid}
    asdf
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[important theorem]
\label{thm:important}
    asdf
\end{theorem}

\thref{thm:stupid}, \thref{thm:important}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

I would like that, when I refer to the "important theorem" to cite it as "important theorem" rather than "theorem 2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I redefine `\label` to actually set two labels. The first is the regular label, while the is a label that captures `\theoremname` - the macro that holds the name of the theorem contained in the optional argument. It then allows you to use `\nameref{<label>}` to extract that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[thref]{ntheorem}
\let\oldlabel\label
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{% \label{<label>}
  \oldlabel{#1}% Set regular \label
  \ifcsname theoremname\endcsname% Check for existence of \theoremname
    \edef\@currentlabel{\theoremname}% Update reference
    \oldlabel{#1-name}% Set reference
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\nameref}[1]{\ref{#1-name}}% Wrapper for reference of theorem name

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[stupid theorem]
\label{thm:stupid}
    asdf
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[important theorem]
\label{thm:important}
    asdf
\end{theorem}

\thref{thm:stupid}, \nameref{thm:important}

\end{document}
```

This has not been tested for compatibility with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).